How to determine the "Type" of an fcurve?
The official blender documentation for the type "FCurve" includes this:
driver
    Channel Driver (only set for Driver F-Curves)

However, it does not explain how to determine if an F-Curve is a "Driver F-Curve" or a different type.   Does anyone know that bit of information?

If the fcurve.driver is None, the fcurve type is Action F-Curve, otherwise Driver F-Curve
import bpy

ob = bpy.context.object
ob.keyframe_insert("location")
ob.driver_add("scale")

def is_driver_fcurve(fc): return fc.driver is not None

kf_fcurve = ob.animation_data.action.fcurves[0]
dr_fcurve = ob.animation_data.drivers[0]

print(is_driver_fcurve(kf_fcurve)) # >>>> False
print(is_driver_fcurve(dr_fcurve)) # >>>> True


Thank you, that looks like exactly the solution!
